# Amazon Redshift COMPOUND SORTKEY - does insertion order matter?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Let's say I've created an empty table in Redshift like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   val_1 INT , 
   val_2 INT , 
   val_3 FLOAT
)
COMPOUND SORTKEY(val_1, val_2)
;
```

When I first populate the table (let's say with the results of some query), should the records be inserted in the `SORTKEY` order, using the `ORDER BY` in the code below:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
SELECT val_1, val_2, val_3 FROM other_table
ORDER BY val_1, val_2
```

Or is there no need to do that; i.e. `SORTKEY` ordering of inserted records is handled physically by Redshift itself?  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the same behaviour for `INSERT INTO` as for loading via the `COPY` command, there is no need to order the records first. According to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-load-in-sort-key-order.html) all the following constraints be fulfilled in order to add the records to sorted region of the table - in your example you have a `COMPOUND SORTKEY` of 2 columns:

- The table uses a compound sort key with only one sort column.
- The sort column is NOT NULL.
- The table is 100 percent sorted or empty.
- All the new rows are higher in sort order than the existing rows, including rows marked for deletion. In this instance, Amazon Redshift uses the first eight bytes of the sort key to determine sort order.